# PHP on some file uploads opens a blank php page instead of running the script

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this form in my profile.php

```
<form action="script/fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Select image to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="UploadProfilePicture" value="UploadProfilePicture">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the script/fileupload.php file:

```
<?php
//open  session
session_start();
//Server requests
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if(isset($_POST['UploadProfilePicture'])){
    upload_profile_picture();
  }
}
function upload_profile_picture(){
  //Set where to put picture and the file name after upload
  $target_dir = dirname(__DIR__)."/uploads/profile-pictures/";
  $imageFileType = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]),PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $genereateFileName = 'profile_' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() .".".$imageFileType;
  $target_file = $target_dir . $genereateFileName;
  $location = "uploads/profile-pictures/".$genereateFileName;
  $uploadOk = 1;
  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $error = "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  }
  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      $error = "Sorry, file already exists. Please change the name and upload again.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Check file size
  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo 'yes';
      $error = "Sorry, your file is too large. Maximum file dize 500kb";
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // Allow certain file formats
  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
      $error = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  //Check if user is logged in
  if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $error = "Only registered users can upload pictures.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  if ($uploadOk == 1) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $text = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        $error = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. Try again or contact administration";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  }
  //Redirect back to page
  if($uploadOk == 1){
    $_SESSION['text'] = $text;
  } else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
  }
  header("Location: ../profile.php");
  die();
}
?>
```

I am testing it on my localhost (I am using WAMP) and it all works like a charm. It catches if it is an image or not, it catches if the file is larger than 500kb. If everything is correct it uploads the pictures to my desired directory.

However I noticed that if I select a big file (larger than 3MB) it just crashes and opens a blank page script/fileupload.php if you refresh it stays on the blank page no script is running. I tried to put an echo "working"; as first line to see if it runs and it does not get executed.

Has anyone got into this trouble and do you know any possible solutions?
With testing I have noticed that it stops working as soon as I select a file to upload that is larger than 3MB doesn't matter if its a picture or not it just opens uploadfiles.php as blank page. If file is lower than 3MB it runs like a charm.

Now I do not understand why does it crash because my script should catch that its a large file and just give an error.

Thanks a lot for any insights!

[EDIT]
As Chris recommended I checked the log and found this in PHP error log:

```
PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 14755394 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

So it does crash because of too big file size. Now is it possible to read the file before making a POST request so that php would not crash?

Comment: Would think `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are good places to start.  I'm not clear on what you are describing though.  Please elaborate on 'opens a blank page'.  I assume the page that loads is the one you posted to but no file uploaded?  Use your browser dev tools to see what is actually happening there.  Warning makes sense.  A *crash* does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I would recommend reading your httpd error log to see if there's more information. Other than that, open your php.ini file and look for **upload_max_file_size**, try increasing the value to something like 128M.

**Edit** (see comment):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['file']) {
      if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 3145728) { //3 MB
          // error
      } else {
          // fine
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes i checked the log and found this in PHP error log:  
  
`PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 14755394 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0 `

So it does crash because of too big file size. Now is it possible to read the file before making a POST request so that php would not crash?

Comment: It sounds as though the max_upload_filesize directive in your php.ini configuration file is restricting the upload file size limit, increasing that value (wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini) should solve the problem of your script crashing and allow you to upload larger files without issue.

Alternatively, check for the file size and throw an error by doing the following (edited my original answer to include code).